# How to fix a color error when using a screw modifier

Tags: modifiers

I made a donut-shaped object using a screw modifier

[image]

The surface color of the object should be white, but it comes out black. Whatever the color of the object changes.

I want a white donut-shaped object, not black.

[image]

Comment: This is completely wrong way to try to do this... why is it black you ask? It is not due to color or lighting, but because of **Z-clipping** (or maybe it is called different, not sure)... the thing is that the way you create your torus shape it has not a single face on those black parts but multiple faces in the same position, Blender then isn't sure which one is the top and they render in the same spot making that black color... there actually is no way to fix this because you need to use different approach to this problem... **make a circle, extrude it with scale and extrude it to the side**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using the *Screw* modifier correctly, you're using a cube but the *Screw* modifier doesn't work like the *Array* modifier, it needs a profile mesh, in your case a simple plane. With a cube you'll have overlapping faces, therefore your artefacts here:

[image]